# Working with Image J : ImageJ cannot detect cells

Tags: image, imagej

![enter image description here][1]

I have been trying to analyze an image for a while. It was obtained after some HeLa cells were exposed to ultrasound waves for 50ms. Is there anyway I can use imageJ to analyze cell data? I've tried using the normal Image->Adjust-> Threshold. Hasn't been working too well, any suggestions? 
You can get the image here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKbcezW-5hYNElaUXZHT3dGa2s/view?usp=sharing .It's not allowing me post it directly

Comment: Probably there is a missing image in your post.

Comment: you can get the image here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKbcezW-5hYNElaUXZHT3dGa2s/view?usp=sharing. It's not allowing me post it up. Thanks

Comment: That image is going to be difficult to detect cells in even for a human.  You need to find a way to increase the contrast.  Maybe phase contrast or DIC microscopy?  Also consider using immunofluorescence or some sort of reporter?  What do you expect the response to be?

Comment: http://zeiss-campus.magnet.fsu.edu/articles/basics/contrast.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ImageJ wiki's guide to segmentation:

```
http://imagej.net/Segmentation
```

In particular, try out the Trainable Weka Segmentation plugin:

```
http://imagej.net/Trainable_Weka_Segmentation
```

If you post an image, perhaps we can offer more specific suggestions.

Comment: Hey, you can view the image I was talking about here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKbcezW-5hYNElaUXZHT3dGa2s/view?usp=sharing. It's not allowing me post it directly. Thanks

Comment: Extremely tough image. What information exactly are you hoping to extract?

Comment: cell lengths, area and all of that. Thanks

Comment: With that image, I have a very hard time differentiating cells even by human eye. Is there any methodological change you can make to your acquisition to make things more distinct? (I am far from expert on acquisition technologies, but the ultrasound images of HeLa cells even in [this old paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0301562977900722), for example are much clearer than your example.) What is that template in the background? Any way you can collect a background image of that to subtract?